# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'MySQLdb' in python

Tags: mysql, python-3.x

**python3, ubuntu-18.04.** error while i am trying to install **"pip3 install mysqlclient"**

```
Collecting mysqlclient
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/d0/97/7326248ac8d5049968bf4ec708a5d3d4806e412a42e74160d7f266a3e03a/mysqlclient-1.4.6.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    /bin/sh: 1: mysql_config: not found
    /bin/sh: 1: mariadb_config: not found
    /bin/sh: 1: mysql_config: not found
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-install-5b_sk5aq/mysqlclient/setup.py", line 16, in <module>
        metadata, options = get_config()
      File "/tmp/pip-install-5b_sk5aq/mysqlclient/setup_posix.py", line 61, in get_config
        libs = mysql_config("libs")
      File "/tmp/pip-install-5b_sk5aq/mysqlclient/setup_posix.py", line 29, in mysql_config
        raise EnvironmentError("%s not found" % (_mysql_config_path,))
    OSError: mysql_config not found

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-install-5b_sk5aq/mysqlclient/
```

Comment: when i am installing this package i found above error @EmrahDiril

Comment: [mysqlclient PyPI page](https://pypi.org/project/mysqlclient/) says there are other things you need to install before you can install mysqlclient. See under "Prerequisites". Have you installed those?